# unable to access admin area processwire using php webserver

Tags: php, routes, processwire

I have a fresh install of Processwire, and I've set the admin area to 'admin'.

However, as I'm using a Cloud9 selfhosted IDE, I run my dev projects using the PHP webserver.

I cannot access the admin panel, as the routing is designed around a .htaccess rewrite

I followed this guide https://processwire.com/talk/topic/13445-using-phps-built-in-webserver-with-processwire/ to create a routing file, but with no joy.

How can I get a dev processwire site up and running using the PHP server?

Answer (score 0):

Run `php -S localhost:8000 routing.php` from the web root. The [routing.php file](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/13445-using-phps-built-in-webserver-with-processwire/) should be there, of course.